# Are voting system and voting theory on topic?

Tags: discussion, voting

There is a [new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97790/voting-systems) in area 51 about voting systems.

Are questions on voting systems and voting theory welcome here? Under what conditions?

Comment: Voting theory is also on-topic in Math.SE (from a mathematical viewpoint, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a tag for [voting-systems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-systems).  I would find your six questions to be on-topic.  Note that some of them might be considered under-researched.  Also

"What single-mark voting rules are there other than Plurality?" is likely too broad.  List questions are almost always off-topic on any Stack Exchange.

"Why is plurality so popular?" might be closed as opinion-based -- you might have to work to phrase it in an objectively measurable way.

While it may be possible to come up with a voting system that is not on-topic for Politics.SE, it seems difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What would you think of more theoretical questions like: 
`Is there an equivalent of Arrow's Impossibility Theorem for systems that choose only one winner (instead of producing a complete societal ranking)?`

Comment: I personally see no reason why purely theoretical questions should be off-topic.